# Where does the upgrade to macOS Catalina and Big Sur move root "/" directory files?

Tags: macos, catalina, upgrade, big-sur

After updating to macOS Catalina, all the folders I had saved in the root directory, "/", were missing.

I read that the system is now read-only, but didn't see a notice on where previous files have gone.

Are they on the system or do I need to restore them from backup?

Comment: For more info: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650 "About the read only system in Mac OS Catalina"

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This took me a long time to figure out, but any file that was formerly at, e.g., `/my-cool-directory` was moved to `/Users/Shared/Relocated Items/Security/my-cool-directory`.

I ended up moving the directories by running this command from the terminal:

```
cd "/Users/Shared/Relocated Items/Security"
sudo mv my-cool-directory ~/
# enter your system password when it asks you
```

After doing that, my file is then located in my home directory, e.g. `~/my-cool-directory`

After a subsequent Mac OS X update, the files may be in `/Users/Shared/Previously Relocated Items.`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101644/discussion-on-answer-by-plowman-where-does-the-upgrade-to-macos-catalina-move-ro).

Comment: As an alternative to the home `~` directory, `my-cool-directory` can also be moved to `/private`. It will sit there more prominently than in the home directory.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the file /etc/synthetic.conf to map your old folder to a new virtual folder on the root directory.
If the file doesn't exists, just create it with sudo :

```
sudo nano /etc/synthetic.conf
```

Add the folder you want to use in the root directory, and the directory you want to mount on.

Ex:

```
my-cool-directory  /Users/Shared/Relocated Items/Security/my-cool-directory
```

Finish by rebooting your mac.

PS: Be careful with your synthetic.conf file. A colleague emailed the content of his file and it had a space between the virtual name and the path. Your system will simply power-off about 15 seconds into the boot process.

You must have only one tab character only between `my-cool-directory` and `/Users/Shared/Relocated Items/Security/my-cool-directory`.

You can find more infos with `man synthetic.conf`

Comment: This worked great, the tab between was definitely key!

Comment: I cannot find /etc/synthetic.conf on Catalina (10.15.4), though there is still a man page for it.  Any idea where it went?

Comment: @ScottSmith The file doesn't exist by default - if you want to use the firmlink functionality described you'll need to create the file from scratch.